# Unity HDRP Dark Pixels on random objects and edges

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, lighting

I have been trying to fix this problem for the past 5 days
There are a lot of annoying dark pixels on multiple random objects.

Examples:

Walls/Pillar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP6Lm.png (Getting closer to them it disappears It only appears in a far distance)

Floor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsvlH.png (For the floor this is different. Still can see it no matter the distance)

I have a strong feeling this has to be a lighting problem that I can't fix.

These are my light settings for all the lights:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ptuq.png

Unity Version: 2020.3.20f1

[These pixels do not appear in the dark so removing the lights I can see it only a little until its completely dark]

[I tried fixing uv overlapping which I don't think is the cause, but I failed trying to fix after working on it for like 8 hours which is annoying as hell.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the glitch by lowering the range of the lights down and increasing the environment lights the place looks a little different but its worth it

Before: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/963813974669930516/970238045964087326/unknown.png

After:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/963813974669930516/970239235808452618/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

Pixelation can occure due to low Lightmap/Shadowmap resolution.
Try to increase the texture size of the Lightmap and change filter/compression modes.

Comment: How do I change Lightmap/Shadowmap resolution?

Comment: You are using baked indirect and realtime light, right? (Because you use "mixed mode" as light type) The resolution settings for the baked light can be found under Window -> Rendering -> Lighting

Comment: Thank you but changing the settings nothing worked, but I think it has something to do with the lights range overlapping? When I lowered the range of the light until it's not overlapping the pixel is no longer there, but my problem is the place is gonna be very dark. Still trying to fix this problem asap https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/940824238296821812/968127288854077490/unknown.png

Comment: So anything I can do about it? Had to delay my games release because of this problem and other problems

Comment: it is hard to say, lighting artifacts can occure due to various reason.

Comment: most of the times, you could fix it by using different  lighting settings. Sometimes its a bug of a specific unity version. Check out the release dates of them.  You could also try out a different light baking system: i.e. Bakery - Light Mapper from the Unity Asset Store. We use it in some projects and in most cases it has better results than the integrated unity light system.